# how to force matplotlib to update a plot

Tags: python, qt4, matplotlib, pyqt4, signals-slots

I am trying to construct a little GUI that has a plot which updates every time a new data sample is read.  I would prefer not to run it with a timer, since the data will be arriving at differing intervals.  Instead, I'm trying to make an implementation using signals, where the data collection function will emit a signal when data is read, and then the painting function will emit a signal when the painting is completed.

The problem, as it appears right now, is that the canvas is not updating as soon as I call canvas.draw().  When this program runs, data_collect() and paint() alternate sending signals, but the figure is not updated until after I stop the process.  How can I force matplotlib to update the figure whenever paint() is called?

What follows is a relatively simple piece of example code which is not optimal, but hopefully will convey the flavor of what I'm trying to do...

```
N_length = 150;
count = [0];

def sinval(delay):

    k = 0;
    x = [];

    # set up data vector with sinusoidal data in it.
    while k < N_length:  
        x.append(math.sin(2*math.pi*k/N_length));
        k += 1;

    def next():

        time.sleep(delay);
        outstring = "%0.3e" % (x[count[0]]);

        if (count[0] == (N_length-1)):
            count[0] = 0;
        else:
            count[0] += 1;

        return outstring;

    return next;


class DesignerMainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_mplMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(DesignerMainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.mplStartButton, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.start_graph);
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.mplStopButton, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.stop_graph);
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.mplQuitButton, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), QtGui.qApp, QtCore.SLOT("quit()"));
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self, QtCore.SIGNAL("data_collect()"), self.data_collect);
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self, QtCore.SIGNAL("paint()"), self.paint);

    def start_graph(self):

        # generates first "empty" plots
        self.user = [];
        self.l_user, = self.mpl.canvas.ax.plot([], self.user, label='sine wave');

        # set up the axes. 
        self.mpl.canvas.ax.set_xlim(0, 300);
        self.mpl.canvas.ax.set_ylim(-1.1, 1.1);
        self.mpl.canvas.draw();

        # start the data collection process.
        self.delay = 0.05;
        self.next = sinval(self.delay);
        self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('data_collect()'));


    def data_collect(self):
        outstring = self.next();
        self.user.append(float(outstring.split()[0]));
        self.l_user.set_data(range(len(self.user)), self.user);
        self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('paint()'));


    def paint(self):
        self.mpl.canvas.draw();
        self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('data_collect()'));
```

Comment: Am I missing something, or have you left out all the plot commands? Neither `data_collect` nor `paint` seem to have any plot commands (like `self.mpl.canvas.ax.plot`) which would alter the plot. So wouldn't calling `self.mpl.canvas.draw()` just redraw the same old plot?

Comment: @~unutbu - He's setting the updating the data of the plot with `self.l_user.set_data(...)` rather than replotting everything.  (It's much more efficient than a call to plot, if you just want to change the plot's data and not redraw the axis ticks, etc.)

Comment: my understanding was that updating l_user.set_data and then invoking canvas.draw() would automatically refresh the figure.  I tried changing the first command in paint(self) to self.mpl.canvas.ax.plot(), but that didn't seem to do the job.  how should I change this command?

thanks -

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess that calling QCoreApplication::processEvents after paint() will help. More elegant would be to have a separate QThread for the reading. Take a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446955/real-time-update-a-qt-textview/3465459#3465459).

Comment: Thanks!  I had to call QtGui.QApplication.processEvents() in PyQt4, but this did the trick.